# Generar animacion de una pista de audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Quisiera saber cómo poder realizar una animación con cualquier sonido como la de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado como hacerlo pero no encuentro mucha información.

Esto he intentado :

```
import wave
import struct
import sys
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = sys.argv([1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Open the wave file and get info
    wave_file = wave.open(filename, 'r')
    data_size = wave_file.getnframes()
    sample_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
    sample_width = wave_file.getsampwidth()
    duration = data_size / float(sample_rate)

# Read in sample data
sound_data = wave_file.readframes(data_size)

# Close the file, as we don't need it any more
wave_file.close()

# Unpack the binary data into an array
unpack_fmt = '%dh' % (data_size)
sound_data = struct.unpack(unpack_fmt, sound_data)

# Process many samples
fouriers_per_second = 24 # Frames per second
fourier_spread = 1.0/fouriers_per_second
fourier_width = fourier_spread
fourier_width_index = fourier_width * float(sample_rate)

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    length_to_process = int(duration)-1
else:
    length_to_process = float(sys.argv[2])



total_transforms = int(round(length_to_process * fouriers_per_second))
fourier_spacing = round(fourier_spread * float(sample_rate))


print ("For Fourier width of "+str(fourier_width)+" need "+str(fourier_width_index)+" samples each FFT")
print ("Doing "+str(fouriers_per_second)+" Fouriers per second")
print ("Total " + str(total_transforms * fourier_spread))
print ("Spacing: "+str(fourier_spacing))
print ("Total transforms "+str(total_transforms))

lastpoint=int(round(length_to_process*float(sample_rate)+fourier_width_index))-1

sample_size = fourier_width_index
freq = sample_rate / sample_size * np.arange(sample_size)

x_axis = range(0, 12)

def getBandWidth():
    return (2.0/sample_size) * (sample_rate / 2.0)

def freqToIndex(f):
    # If f (frequency is lower than the bandwidth of spectrum[0]
    if f < getBandWidth()/2:
        return 0
    if f > (sample_rate / 2) - (getBandWidth() / 2):
        return sample_size -1
    fraction = float(f) / float(sample_rate)
    index = round(sample_size * fraction)
    return index

fft_averages = []

def average_fft_bands(fft_array):
    num_bands = 12 # The number of frequency bands (12 = 1 octave)
    del fft_averages[:]
    for band in range(0, num_bands):
        avg = 0.0

        if band == 0:
            lowFreq = int(0)
        else:
            lowFreq = int(int(sample_rate / 2) / float(2 ** (num_bands - band)))
        hiFreq = int((sample_rate / 2) / float(2 ** ((num_bands-1) - band)))
        lowBound = int(freqToIndex(lowFreq))
        hiBound = int(freqToIndex(hiFreq))
        for j in range(lowBound, hiBound):
            avg += fft_array[j]

        avg /= (hiBound - lowBound + 1)
        fft_averages.append(avg)

for offset in range(0, total_transforms):
    start = int(offset * sample_size)
    end = int((offset * sample_size) + sample_size -1)

    print ("Processing sample %i of %i (%d seconds)" % (offset + 1, total_transforms, end/float(sample_rate)))
    sample_range = sound_data[start:end]
    ## FFT the data
    fft_data = abs(np.fft.fft(sample_range))
    # Normalise the data a second time, to make numbers sensible
    fft_data *= ((2**.5)/sample_size)
    plt.ylim(0, 1000)
    average_fft_bands(fft_data)
    y_axis = fft_averages
    """Stuff for bar graph"""
    width = 0.35
    p1 = plt.bar(x_axis, y_axis, width, color='r')
    """End bar graph stuff"""
    filename = str('frame_%05d' % offset) + '.png'
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi=100)
    plt.close()
print ("DONE!")
```

Comment: Hola Angel. Sería interesante que mostraras qué has intentado, para poder empezar por algo

Comment: @federqui, la verdad es que no he podido intentar nada... El único articulo que encontré es algo sobre la transformada rápida de fourier. Sin embargo no logré comprender como la utilizan por eso estoy en busca de un ejemplo

Comment: @fedorqui, la verdad es que no he podido intentar nada... El único articulo que encontré es algo sobre la transformada rápida de fourier. Sin embargo no logré comprender como la utilizan por eso estoy en busca de un ejemplo –

Comment: Genial, añadiste lo que has intentado. Ahora la siguiente pregunta es: ¿qué problemas te está dando? ¿dónde se atasca?

Comment: @fedorqui, el problema es que no se como hacer para que las barras que genera sean inguales a las del gif que esta en la parte de arriba....

Comment: @fedorqui, el problema es que no se como hacer para que las barras que genera sean inguales a las del gif que esta en la parte de arriba.